# Getting 2d array from a method where I use switch

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement, return-value

Hi I would like to get 2d array out of a method where I use switch statement. I would like to get out num1 or num2, so the other methods can use this numbers. Is this possible, how?
This is my code:

```
public int[][] gameNumbers(){

    int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 2) + 1;

    switch(rand) {
    case 1:
        int [][] num1= {{4,3,5,2,6,9,7,8,1},{6,8,2,5,7,1,4,9,3},{1,9,7,8,3,4,5,6,2},{8,2,6,1,9,5,3,4,7},{3,7,4,6,8,2,9,1,5},{9,5,1,7,4,3,6,2,8},{5,1,9,3,2,6,8,7,4},{2,4,8,9,5,7,1,3,6},{7,6,3,4,1,8,2,5,9}};
        break;
    case 2:
        int [][] num2= {{1,7,4,3,5,2,9,6,8},{5,3,6,8,7,1,6,4,5,3},{2,9,8,7,1,6,4,5,3},{4,2,3,1,7,8,6,9,5},{8,5,7,2,6,9,3,4,1},{9,6,1,4,3,5,7,8,2},{3,8,2,6,4,7,5,1,9},{7,4,9,5,2,1,8,3,6},{6,1,5,9,8,3,2,7,4}};
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return rand;
}
```

Comment: Can the arrays be random? If so why not just generate a random array instead of having a `switch`?

Comment: Also if you don't do anything in the `default` case you don't need to write it. And your method is wrong it is returning an invalid type since in the signature you have it returning `int[][]` and you're trying to return simply `int`.

Comment: @chriptus13 the arrays cant be random, those are arrays for sudoku :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close. This should do it.

Declare the result variable before the switch statement, and assign it inside the switch.

```
public int[][] gameNumbers(){

    // Declare this before the switch so it stays in scope.
    int[][] result;

    int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    switch(rand) {
    case 1:
        result = new int[][]{{4,3,5,2,6,9,7,8,1},{6,8,2,5,7,1,4,9,3},{1,9,7,8,3,4,5,6,2},{8,2,6,1,9,5,3,4,7},{3,7,4,6,8,2,9,1,5},{9,5,1,7,4,3,6,2,8},{5,1,9,3,2,6,8,7,4},{2,4,8,9,5,7,1,3,6},{7,6,3,4,1,8,2,5,9}};
        break;

    case 2:
        result = new int[][]{{1,7,4,3,5,2,9,6,8},{5,3,6,8,7,1,6,4,5,3},{2,9,8,7,1,6,4,5,3},{4,2,3,1,7,8,6,9,5},{8,5,7,2,6,9,3,4,1},{9,6,1,4,3,5,7,8,2},{3,8,2,6,4,7,5,1,9},{7,4,9,5,2,1,8,3,6},{6,1,5,9,8,3,2,7,4}};
        break;

    default:
        result = null;
        break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to get one of possible ten 9x9 arrays you can try it like this. You place those ten arrays in another array and then just return one at random.

```java
private static int[][][] arrays = new int[][][]{
        {{4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 9, 7, 8, 1}, {6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 1, 4, 9, 3}, {1, 9, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2}, {8, 2, 6, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 7}, {3, 7, 4, 6, 8, 2, 9, 1, 5}, {9, 5, 1, 7, 4, 3, 6, 2, 8}, {5, 1, 9, 3, 2, 6, 8, 7, 4}, {2, 4, 8, 9, 5, 7, 1, 3, 6}, {7, 6, 3, 4, 1, 8, 2, 5, 9}},
        {{1, 7, 4, 3, 5, 2, 9, 6, 8}, {5, 3, 6, 8, 7, 1, 6, 4, 5, 3}, {2, 9, 8, 7, 1, 6, 4, 5, 3}, {4, 2, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6, 9, 5}, {8, 5, 7, 2, 6, 9, 3, 4, 1}, {9, 6, 1, 4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 2}, {3, 8, 2, 6, 4, 7, 5, 1, 9}, {7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 1, 8, 3, 6}, {6, 1, 5, 9, 8, 3, 2, 7, 4}}
        // ... more 8 arrays
};

public int[][] gameNumbers() {
    int idx = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    return arrays[idx];
}
```

Comment: No, what I want is to select one array from arrays in switch cases. That is the problem, I dont know how to get them out of switch.

Comment: Check the second approach.

Comment: Yes I thought about using if statements, but I want to have ten 2d arrays, so should I just use if and else if statements? Like if(math.rand() == 1), else if(math.rand() == 2)...?

Comment: Oh in that case use the `switch`.

Comment: You could even put those ten arrays into an array and index it using the random result. That way you can have it as a single line.

Comment: I am trying, but how do I use the switch? I have no idea :(

Comment: I mean I dont know how to get array out of switch.
"You could even put those ten arrays into an array and index it using the random result. That way you can have it as a single line. – chriptus13" - do you mean like an ArrayList?